# masking presented view controller with CAShapeLayer also mask the presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift, mask, cashapelayer

like the titles says, i have a first view controller (VC1) that presents a second one (VC2) modaly. on VC2 i apply a resizable mask on `self.view.layer.mask` that changes its size with a pan gesture, but when the mask resizes i don't see VC1 behind VC2, i see just black color which is the `.backgroundColor` of the application's `UIWindow`. both `self.view.clipToBounds` and `self.view.layer.masksToBounds` are set to `true` on `self.view` of VC2. why is that? thanks

video of bug: https://youtu.be/9Kda10Sl2g8

i managed to go around it as @nguyenbao95 suggested in his comment: Add another UIView to VC2's self.view (this view is above the snapshot), then add all your content to this view. And mask this view.

i suspect that when i modaly present VC2 then VC1 is no longer visible behind VC2 until it is needed again.

Answer (score 1):

Before you present the second VC, just take screenshot of the first VC. And then add an UIImageView with this image to the second VC.

Hope it will solves your problem

Comment: is this how i'm supposed to go about it? does a `CAShapeLayer` mask supposed to mask all the view hierarchy behind it or just the view it is applied on?

Comment: i tried it and it just masks the snapshot as well.. and also hides the rest of VC2 even though i sent `snapshotView` to the back of VC2's `self.view`

Comment: I still don't understand your answer, could you give me a picture?

Comment: here is [with snapshot](https://youtu.be/kEDlHiv3WCs), and here is [without snapshot](https://youtu.be/9Kda10Sl2g8).

Comment: Have you debugged view hierarchy to make sure that the snapshot is already added to self.view of VC2?

Comment: yes it is in the view hierarchy and also it is visible in the video, the two VCs have different background color. but what I'm saying is that if the snapshot is a subview of VC2's `self.view` then it will also be masked, no?

Comment: As i know, if snapshot is a subview of VC2's self.view, it will also be masked.

Try this way:
Add another UIView to VC2's self.view (this view is above the snapshot) then add all your content to this view. And mask this view.

Comment: yes so i want VC1 to still be visible behind the mask of VC2, and not for the snapshot also to be masked.

Comment: Try this way:
Add another UIView to VC2's self.view (this view is above the snapshot), then add all your content to this view. And mask this view.

Comment: yes, it did the work, thanks :) i suspect that when i modaly present VC2 then VC1 is no longer visible in the background.